# Make a select query from two table with where clause.

Tags: php, mysql

I have two variables `$code` and `$name`. `$code probably have tutor's code or institute's code and`$name also probably have tutor's name or institute's name.

This is the way the names come to `$code` and `$name`

```
// Check Tutor or Institute
if ( $tutorCode && $tutorName) {
    $code = $tutorCode;
    $name = $tutorName;
} elseif ( $instituteCode && $instituteName) {
    $code = $instituteCode;
    $name = $instituteName;
}
```

My problem is I need to get email address from `contact` table according to this `$code` and `$name`. Need to check two table `tutor` and `institute` which belong to code and name.

`tutor` and `institute` table have `contact_id` and `contact` table also have `contact_id`.
`tutor` table have `tutor_code` and `tutor_name`.
`institute` table have `institute_code` and `institute_name`

I tried something like this. but can't check in both tables.

```
$q = "SELECT email FROM tutor 
      WHERE tutor_code = $code AND tutor_name = $name"
```

Hope someone will help me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can `UNION` both tables

```
SELECT  email, code, name
FROM
(
    SELECT email, tutor_code as code, tutor_name as Name FROM tutor
    UNION ALL
    SELECT email, institute_code  as code, institute_name as Name FROM institute
) sub
WHERE   code = $code AND
        name = '$name'
```

or

```
SELECT  s.*, c.*
FROM
        (
            SELECT  contact_ID, 
                    tutor_code as code, 
                    tutor_name as Name,
                    'TUTOR' sourceTbl
            FROM    tutor
            WHERE   tutor_code = $code AND
                    tutor_name = '$name'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  contact_ID,
                    institute_code  as code, 
                    institute_name as Name,
                    'INSTITUTE' sourceTbl
            FROM    institute
            WHERE   institute_code = $code AND
                    institute_name = '$name'
        ) s
        INNER JOIN contact c
            ON s.contact_ID = c.contact_ID
```

keep it mind that it will return duplicate record if both records exists on both table because of specifying `ALL` in the `UNION`. If you want to get only unique records, remove `ALL`.

Comment: email field contain in contact table not in ether tutor or institute

Comment: I get this error - #1054 - Unknown column 'code' in 'where clause'

Comment: Can I know is there a way to know selected email from tutor's or institute's using above query?

Answer (score 0):

to look at your query i am noticing that there is issue for $code and $name values.
you need to add $code and $name inside double quote or single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on using joins in mysql.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

And for both the institute and tutor part, you could use a UNION or joins.
In your case it would look something like this:

```
$q = "SELECT c.email 
      FROM contact c 
      LEFT JOIN tutor t on t.contact_id = c.contact_id
      LEFT JOIN institute i on i.contact_id = c.contact_id
      WHERE 
      ( 
          (t.tutor_code = $code AND t.tutor_name = $name) OR
          (i.institute_code = $code AND i.institute_name = $name) OR
      )";
```