# Select data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, union, subquery

I am trying to get some data from db.

1. `username` from login table
2. `email` from contact table

checking with 2 values in two tables `tutor` and `institute`

This is my code so far :

```
SELECT s. * , c.email, l.username
FROM (
        SELECT  contact_id AS id, 
                  login_id, 
                  username, 
                  tutor_code AS code, 
                  tutor_name AS Name, 
                  'tutor' AS profile
        FROM tutors
        WHERE tutor_code = $code AND tutor_name = '$name'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  contact_id AS id, 
                  login_id, 
                  username, 
                  institute_code AS code, 
                  institute_name AS Name, 
                  'institute' AS profile
        FROM institutes
        WHERE institute_code = $code AND institute_name = '$name'
        )
INNER JOIN contact c ON s.id = c.contact_id
INNER JOIN login l ON s.login_id = l.login_id
```

This query is not working and there is an error message.

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'username' in 'field list'

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT s. * , c.email, l.username
FROM (
        SELECT  contact_id AS id, 
                  login_id, 
                  username, 
                  tutor_code AS code, 
                  tutor_name AS Name, 
                  'tutor' AS profile
        FROM tutors
        WHERE tutor_code = $code AND tutor_name = '$name'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  contact_id AS id, 
                  login_id, 
                  username, 
                  institute_code AS code, 
                  institute_name AS Name, 
                  'institute' AS profile
        FROM institutes
        WHERE institute_code = $code AND institute_name = '$name'
        )s
INNER JOIN contact c ON s.id = c.contact_id
INNER JOIN login l ON s.login_id = l.login_id
```

Comment: are you sure username field exists in login table ?

Comment: are you sure username exists in the institutes and tutors tables?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354226/make-a-select-query-from-two-table-with-where-clause ???

Comment: A breakdown of the tables would help so we know what columns where expected.

Comment: I am not sure about `s` no table is been alias defined for it.

Comment: username field in my login table. 100% sure

Comment: @nvanesch no. its make with 2 table this is the problem with 3 tables

Comment: you need to use `as anyname` when your subquery closed..like SELECT s. * , c.email, l.username
FROM (select -----
        )UNION ALL
        (SELECT  
        ----
        ) `as abc`
INNER JOIN contact c ON s.id = c.contact_id
INNER JOIN login l ON s.login_id = l.login_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears you are retrieving your `username` from `login`, the column `username` most likely doesn't exist in `tutors` and/or `institutes`, it is also not necessary for the join to `login` because you are joining on `login_id`, I think you could just remove the `username` columns from your subquery:

```
SELECT s. * , c.email, l.username
FROM (
        SELECT  contact_id AS id, 
                  login_id, 
                  --username, 
                  tutor_code AS code, 
                  tutor_name AS Name, 
                  'tutor' AS profile
        FROM tutors
        WHERE tutor_code = $code AND tutor_name = '$name'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  contact_id AS id, 
                  login_id, 
                  --username, 
                  institute_code AS code, 
                  institute_name AS Name, 
                  'institute' AS profile
        FROM institutes
        WHERE institute_code = $code AND institute_name = '$name'
        ) s
INNER JOIN contact c ON s.id = c.contact_id
INNER JOIN login l ON s.login_id = l.login_id
```

*I've also added the alias `s` to your subuqery as I assume it's omission was a typo as it would throw a syntax error in its absence*

Comment: alias was type. your solution is ok. Its working now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to call `username` from `tutors` and from `institutes` table and use `as abc` when your subquery closed like

```
SELECT s. * , c.email, l.username
FROM (
        SELECT  contact_id AS id, 
                  login_id, 
                  tutor_code AS code, 
                  tutor_name AS Name, 
                  'tutor' AS profile
        FROM tutors
        WHERE tutor_code = $code AND tutor_name = '$name'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  contact_id AS id, 
                  login_id, 
                  institute_code AS code, 
                  institute_name AS Name, 
                  'institute' AS profile
        FROM institutes
        WHERE institute_code = $code AND institute_name = '$name'
        ) as s
INNER JOIN contact c ON s.id = c.contact_id
INNER JOIN login l ON s.login_id = l.login_id
```

This query will return you Duplicate entries because you are using `ALL` in `union`.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: If you are aliasing the subquery as `abc` you also need to update where the alias `s` has been used (`s.*`, `s.login_id = l.login_id`, `s.id = c.contact_id`)

Comment: @GarethD yes you are right need to update `s` to `abc` but i changed `abc` to `s`..thanks for suggestion..

Answer (score -1):

It's the `username` field in the subquery that isn't found, you have to include the `login` table in the subqueries.

```
SELECT s. * , c.email, l.username
FROM (
        SELECT  contact_id AS id, 
                  login_id, 
                  l1.username, 
                  tutor_code AS code, 
                  tutor_name AS Name, 
                  'tutor' AS profile
        FROM tutors t
        INNER JOIN login l1 ON l1.login_id = t.login_id
        WHERE tutor_code = $code AND tutor_name = '$name'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  contact_id AS id, 
                  login_id, 
                  l2.username, 
                  institute_code AS code, 
                  institute_name AS Name, 
                  'institute' AS profile
        FROM institutes i
        INNER JOIN login l2 ON l2.login_id = i.login_id
        WHERE institute_code = $code AND institute_name = '$name'
        )
INNER JOIN contact c ON s.id = c.contact_id
INNER JOIN login l ON s.login_id = l.login_id
```

Comment: Okay @TNK I forgot the 'ON' keyword and 'i' in the institutes `INNER JOIN`, I modified the answer, could you try again?